# Connecting already existing MySQL table to already existing Scaffold

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I know that it is certainly possible to connect an already-existing MySQL database to a completely new Rails application through `rake db:schema:dump` and by configuring the `database.yml` file, as shown in a couple of Stack Overflow questions and through this blog: [Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Creating a Rails Instance from an Existing MySQL DB](http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2013/02/06/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-creating-a-rails-instance-from-an-existing-mysql-db/).

However, is it possible to link an already existing scaffold in Rails 4.1 - one that is generated through say,

```
rails g scaffold person \
firstname:string lastname:string gender:string age:integer
```

(and this scaffold is generated with the default SQLite setting), and say you have a MySQL database on AWS named `people` with columns `firstname:string lastname:string age:integer`.

Is there some way to link up the rails app to this existing database in such a case?

Comment: yes it is possible. change database.yml accordingly.

Comment: And there would be no issues with transitioning between SQLite - which is the Scaffold's current backend - and MySQL - which is it's new backend?

Comment: read about ActiveRecord

Comment: I have read about both Active Record Query Interface and ActiveRecord::Base. I understand that it connects to this concept to some extent. So from what I understand ActiveRecord basically eliminates the need for manual SQL Querying and allows for you to execute the same Query commands regardless of the type of SQL database type? I assume that's why there will be no problem as long as my database column names are the same?

Comment: What ActiveRecord does, in short, is it abstracts the DB backend so you don't have to care about it as long as you don't do anything DB specific.